# If a Laplacian eigenfunction is zero in an open set, is it identically zero?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

This seems like it should be easy but I can't seem to figure it out.

Suppose $f$ satisfies $\Delta f + \lambda f = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (where $\lambda > 0$ is a constant), and in some open set $U$ we have $f = 0$. Does this mean $f = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

My idea for solving it:

Suppose not; WLOG suppose $U$ is a maximal open set ordered by inclusion in which $f = 0$. Let $x \in \partial U$.

If $x$ has a neighborhood where $f \le 0$, then $\Delta f \ge 0$ there, so $f$ is subharmonic and by the maximum principle, $f = 0$ in the neighborhood, contradicting the maximality of $U$.

If $x$ has a neighborhood where $f \ge 0$ then the same argument applies to $-f$ (or the same argument with "superharmonic" and "minimum principle").

Here is where I'm stuck: How do I rule out a third possibility, where every neighborhood of $x$ contains positive and negative points?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property you are looking for is called Unique Continuation Property, (UCP) for short, and it is satisfied for example, by analytic functions.

As @uvs pointed out, every eigenfunction is analytical in the interior of $\Omega$ where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a open set. A proof of this fact can be found [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540660984) in chapter 5. Also, take a look in this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540660992), page 108 onwards and you will find plenty of nice properties of eigenfunctions of the laplacian.

[Here](http://www3.nd.edu/~qhan/nodal.pdf) you will find more specialized properties of harmonic functions and eigenfunctions of the Dirichlet problem.

Now let $p\in (1,\infty)$. Define formally $\Delta_pu=\operatorname{div}(|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u)$ and consider the problem $$-\Delta_p u=\lambda |u|^{p-2}u,\ u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)\tag{1}$$

If $p=2$, problem (1) reduces to the classic laplacian eigenvalue problem. It is a open problem to know whether the soltuions of (1) (with $p\neq 2$) satisfies the UCP. Even for $p$-harmonic functions, i.e. functions which satisfies (1) with $\lambda=0$, this is a open problem (at least in my humble knowledge) excluding only the case $n=2$.

In the case $n=2$, i.e. the planar case, $p$-harmonic functions are know to be quasiconformal maps and consequently quasisymetric maps, which implies some good properties, like for example, that the set where $\nabla u =0$ is discrete. For references, take a look on this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198509294). Also, these are interesting papers: [Granlund-Marola](http://www.helsinki.fi/~marola/julkaisuja/uniquecont.pdf), [Granlund-Marola 2](http://www.helsinki.fi/~marola/julkaisuja/eigunique.pdf).

Comment: Thanks so much for the very detailed answer and especially all the references :)

Comment: You are welcome. Now you have a lot of things to play :)

Comment: Some of the posted links are broken nowadays. Precisely all the paper-links...? I figured out the titles of the linked papers but it doesn't seem to be easy to find them as open-access nowadays. If someone knows up to date links that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: eigenfunctions of Laplace operator are analytical.

Step 2: analytical functions vanishing on an open set are identically zero.

See, however, this article: http://www.ams.org/notices/201005/rtx100500624p.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it a standard / easy result that eigenfunctions are real-analytic? The books I've been reading only say they're $C^\infty$.