# Why are Dirichlet eigenfunctions real-analytic?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-operators

Consider the eigenvalue problem $\Delta u + \lambda u = 0$ on some bounded domain $\Omega \subset \Bbb R^d$ with smooth boundary, with Dirichlet data $u|_{\partial\Omega} =0$. It is known that solutions $u$ are real-analytic inside $\Omega$.

This is supposed to be a simple fact, but I couldn't find a reference/proof that shows this (that I could understand). I only found references for more advanced stuff, like quasilinear equations with non-analytic coefficients, etc... Anyway, most references I've read try to generalize, which makes it harder to read - I'm not interested in a more general case.

Why is $u$ real-analytic? Does it follow from the Cauchy-Kowalewsky theorem (and if so, how)? Is there a simple proof of this (only for the above PDE, not in general)?

Comment: This is a good question. I recently saw a proof of this theorem in a talk. The point is to obtain pointwise estimates on the higher derivatives of $u$ which do not grow too fast. This allows one to conclude, with a standard argument, that the remainder term in Taylor's formula tends to zero as the degree of the approximating polynomial tends to infinity. The estimates can be obtained by means of the usual elliptic theory toolbox, but frankly I am not able to tell you more.

Comment: (P.S.: You could try looking on Reed & Simon's book "Methods of modern mathematical physics". Look for the keyword "Hartree-Fock theory". )

Comment: I believe that this could be helpful http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672383/if-a-laplacian-eigenfunction-is-zero-in-an-open-set-is-it-identically-zero

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro - I looked in the book(s) but couldn't find what you mentioned... Siminore, the question you linked to was also asked by me :) The reference given there for analyticity was also very hard for me to follow, as I wrote here. It is way too general and very tiring to "translate" the proof to my simple case. All I want is estimation of Taylor coefficients and showing the radius of convergence is positive, as the first comment suggested, in the simple Euclidean case and without a more general differential operator...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The statement really is: if $f$ is a distribution on an open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\Delta f=\lambda f$ then $f$ is real analytic. To prove it:

1: find a distribution $G$ on $\mathbb R^n$ such that $(\Delta-\lambda)G=\delta$. This can be done explicitly via Fourier transform, and the result is a real-analytic function except at $0\in\mathbb R^n$.

2: for any $x\in\Omega$ take a compactly-supported smooth function $\psi$ on $\Omega$ which is equal to $1$ in a neighbourhood of $x$. Let $g=(\Delta-\lambda)(\psi f)$. We have $g=0$ on the open subset where $\psi$ is locally constant. As $g$ has compact support, $\psi f=G\ast g$.

3: as $G$ is real analytic except at  $0$, or equivalently, $G$ is holomorphic in a small neighbourhood of $\mathbb R^n-\{0\}$ in $\mathbb C^n-\{0\}$, the convolution $G\ast g$ is real analytic in the complement of the support of $g$, as there $(G\ast g)(x)=\langle g(y),G(x-y)\rangle$, we can allow $x$ to be complex and differentiate w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: So every linear differential operator whose fundamental solution is analytic on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$ will have analytic solutions, if I understand well.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro yes. Every elliptic operator (with constant coefficients) has this property.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro and it can be even upgraded to any elliptic operator with real analytic coefficients. See Theorem 8.6.1 in Hörmander's ALPDO, volume 1.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a very simple proof assuming you know about the Sobolev embedding theorems.

**Sobolev embedding for domains**
$$ \| u\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)} \leq C_{\Omega,d,s} \| u \|_{H^s_0(\Omega)} \tag{*}$$
if $s > s_0 = d/2$. The space $H^s_0$ is the $L^2$ Sobolev space with $s$ derivatives vanishing on the boundary. For $s$ a positive integer it is the closure of $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ under the norm 
$$ \|u\|_{H^s(\Omega)}^2 = \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + \sum_{|\alpha| \leq s} \|\partial^\alpha u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 $$
where $\alpha$ are multi-indices.

**A priori estimate**
We integrate by parts
$$ \int_{\Omega} u \triangle u = \int_{\Omega} - |\nabla u|^2 $$
assuming Dirichlet boundary conditions. So for Dirichlet eigenfunction we have
$$ \|\nabla u \|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 = \lambda \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 $$
(this is basically the definition from the Rayleigh quotient of the eigenfunction anyway). This implies that 
$$ \| u\|_{H^s}^2 \leq  \|u\|_{L^2} + \lambda \|u\|_{H^{s-1}}^2$$
which implies
$$ \| u\|_{H^s}^2 \leq (1 + \lambda + \cdots + \lambda^s) \|u\|_{L^2}^2 $$
and that for multi-indices $\alpha$, we have
$$ \sum_{|\alpha| = k} \| \partial^\alpha u\|_{H^s}^2 \leq \lambda^{k}(1 + \lambda + \cdots + \lambda^s) \|u\|_{L^2}^2 \tag{**}$$

**Finishing the proof**

The equations ($*$) and ($**$)  combined with $s > s_0$ gives 
$$ \sum_{|\alpha| = k} \| \partial^\alpha u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}^2 \leq C_{d,s,\Omega, \lambda}' \lambda^{k} \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 $$
where we absorbed the factor $(1 + \cdots + \lambda^s)$ into the constant factor; this shows

1. The function is smooth, since all higher derivatives are bounded and
2. The Taylor coefficients grow exponentially in $k$, and hence the Taylor series converge in an open neighbourhood of every point, and hence the function is real analytic.

---

The same argument can be adapted to show the same result for many other linear elliptic operators.

Comment: Another approach is that for general linear elliptic operators one can also directly gain derivatives at $C^k$ norms (instead of Sobolev) using Schauder theory (see, e.g. Chapter 6 of Gilbarg and Trudinger). In the method above we over-shoot by $s$ derivatives and come back down using Sobolev; this over-shooting can be avoided to some extent using $L^\infty$ type estimates. But it doesn't really much since our functions turns out to be smooth anyway ($\infty$ minus a finite number is still infinite). For even better domains (such as the ball), you can simply use the Newton potential.

Comment: You pass from $\| \nabla u \|_{L^2}^2 =\lambda \| u\|_{L^2}^2$ to $\| u\|_{H^s}^2 \le \|u\|_{L^2}^2+ \lambda \| u\|_{H^{s-1}}^2$. Could you please explain how to do that?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: Let me do the case where $s = 2$, the higher cases follow similarly. $$\| u\|_{H^2}^2 = \|u\|_{L^2}^2 + \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2 + \|\nabla\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2 $$ The first term we keep. The second term we know $= \lambda \|u\|_{L^2}^2$. The third term we use that $\triangle u = - \lambda u \implies \triangle \nabla u = - \lambda \nabla u$ so that $\|\nabla\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2 = \lambda \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2$. Regroup and you are done.

Comment: OK, but $\nabla u$ doesn't satisfy the boundary conditions. So how can you integrate by parts (or use Rayleigh quotient)? That's the point that I am failing to understand.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: the most accurate thing to say is that I cheated. :-) In reality you have to cut-off near the boundary and deal with a loss which translates to smaller radius of convergence near the boundary.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense indeed. One cannot expect the solution to be analytic up to the boundary.